# AWS CLI - Get account name from profile name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to create deployment scripts for my aws things.

We've created seperate accounts for production versus development, and I want to pass in an argument where the user can specify which environment to deploy to. Since the profile is what ties them to the account they are using, is there a means to get the account name given the profile name on the command line?

Comment: Have you looked in to doing IaC and a tool like Terraform or the AWS native CloudFormation. It is really the way to go to automate deployments.

Comment: @Dude0001 new to me

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sts get-caller-identity` to get the account ID.  This can generally be done without extended permissions, though requires a non-intuitive mapping of account ID's to your name for the account, though in some cases it's useful since it's deterministic and will be unique between accounts.

```
$ aws --profile profilename sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "#####", 
    "UserId": "ABC", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::#####:user.name"
}
```

You can also use `iam list-account-aliases`, which is easier to use:

```
$ aws --profile profilename iam list-account-aliases
{
    "AccountAliases": [
        "my-company-account-alias"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The later command seems more relevant here as `get-caller-identity` just outputs the account id, not its name.

Comment: `list-account-aliases` won't necessarily give you the account name, just the alias set up in IAM for direct sign-ins to the account. If you've set these up to be the same as the account name, though, it's not a bad option!

Answer (score 1):

The describe-account command will give you the account name

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/describe-account.html

Not clear how this helps you in the goal of automating deployments, but I think it answers your question.